# retrieve getAttribute of clicked element in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have number of images on my webpage.

```
<img id="a" src="1.jpg">
<br>
<img  id="b" src="2.jpg">
```

I am trying to get "src" of clicked images by using below javascript.

```
var getImageName = function(){
     document.onclick = function(){
        var image = this.getAttribute("src");
        alert(image);
        }}

getImageName();
```

But its giving an error this.getAttribute is not function.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `this` is the document object in your click handler, so you may want to check whether the click has happened in an image element

```js
var getImageName = function() {
  document.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
      var image = e.target.getAttribute("src");
      alert(image);
    }
  }
}

getImageName()
```

```html
<img id="a" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=1" />
<br>
<img id="a" src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=2" />
<br>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how this and target are different?

Comment: @Nomad since you have binded the handler to the document object, `this` inside the hadnler will refer to the document object

Comment: @Nomad [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will refer to the element which dispatched the event so it will be the `image` element

Comment: @Nomad see the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) object properties for details