# JavaScript How to get data of an "a" tag when it has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Good day! For example I have this code:

```
<a href="link" onclick="myfunc()">Secret link</a>
```

How can I transmit its values such as: href, and name to the onclick event without defining it in the **myfunc('link', 'name')** explicitly? 
Maybe, there is something like:

```
<a href="link" onclick="myfunc(this)">Secret link</a>
```

P.S. I do not use JQuery

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: "Maybe, there is something like" — Exactly that. Did you try it?

Comment: It would be better to do it without an inline event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve getAttribute of clicked element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380945/retrieve-getattribute-of-clicked-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe, there is something like
>
> ```
> <a href="link" onclick="myfunc(this)">Secret link</a>
> ```

Yes, **exactly** link that. Then in `myfunc`, you use the parameter's properties and/or attributes:

```
function myfunc(link) {
    console.log(link.href);
}
```

The properties of an `HTMLAnchorElement` are listed [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#htmlanchorelement). If you include other information (such as [`data-*` attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)) on the element (or you want the **raw** `href`, not the resolved one), get them via the `getAttribute` method ([DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-getattribute), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)).

---

Since it's a link, though, if you're responding to a click on it you may also want to prevent the link's default action (following the link). To do that, you'd add `return` to the `onclick` and also `return false;` from the handler. Live example:

```js
function myfunc(link) {
  console.log("href property: " + link.href);
  console.log("href attribute: " + link.getAttribute("href"));
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="link" onclick="return myfunc(this)">Secret link</a>
```

---

Rather than using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, though, I do recommend reading up on [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

Comment: I tried this several years ago and it didn't work XD

Comment: @user8661184: First time I used it was ~1996. It worked at least then.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I transmit its values such as: href, and name to the onclick
>   event without defining it in the myfunc('link', 'name') explicitly?

You can get it from `this` itself using `getAttribute` and `innerText`

```
function myfunc( thisObj )
{
   var link = thisObj.getAttribute( "href" );
   var name = thisObj.innerText;
}
```

and pass `this` with `onclick`

```
<a href="link" onclick="myfunc(this)">Secret link</a>
```

Also, try doing it [without inline event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

```
document.querySelector( "a" ).addEventListener( "click", function( event ){
   event.preventDefault(); //to prevent default action of link click
   var link = this.getAttribute( "href" );
   var name = this.innerText;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`getAttribute`**

> ***[getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned
>   will either be null or "" (the empty string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)***

```js
function myfunc(elem) {
  console.log(elem.getAttribute('id'))
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="click" onclick="myfunc(this)">Secret link</a>
```