# Javascript selecting different names from elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have three buttons as:

```
<button name="red" onclick="sayName()">Click</button>
<button name="blue" onclick="sayName()">Click</button>
<button name="green" onclick="sayName()">Click</button>
```

What I would like is, that one of those three buttons is clicked, via sayName() to alert the button name attribute.

Example: If I click the second button, it should alert `blue`, if I click the first it should alert `red` and so on...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retrieve getAttribute of clicked element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380945/retrieve-getattribute-of-clicked-element-in-javascript)

Comment: jhonroger - please see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the name of the button to the onClick() cb:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
<script>
function sayName(name) { alert(name); }
</script>

<button name="red" onclick="sayName(this.name)">Click</button>
<button name="blue" onclick="sayName(this.name)">Click</button>
<button name="green" onclick="sayName(this.name)">Click</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using it like this:

HTML:

```
<button name="red" onclick="sayName('red')">Click</button>
<button name="blue" onclick="sayName('blue')">Click</button>
<button name="green" onclick="sayName('green')">Click</button>
```

or:

```
<button name="red" onclick="sayName(this.name)">Click</button>
<button name="blue" onclick="sayName(this.name)">Click</button>
<button name="green" onclick="sayName(this.name)">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
function sayName(name) {
  if (name === "red") alert("Red Button Clicked");
  if (name === "blue") alert("Blue Button Clicked");
  if (name === "green") alert("Green Button Clicked");
}
```

**OR LISTEN WITH JQUERY**

HTML:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<button name="red" onclick="sayName()">Click</button>
<button name="blue" onclick="sayName()">Click</button>
<button name="green" onclick="sayName()">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
$("button[name='red']").click(function() {
  alert("Red Button Clicked");
})

$("button[name='blue']").click(function() {
  alert("Blue Button Clicked");
})

$("button[name='green']").click(function() {
  alert("Green Button Clicked");
})

function sayName() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event-delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

We add a `onclick`-listener to the parent-element, and use the first parameter (`evt`). Then:

- If the clicked element isn't a `<button>`-element, ignore (`return`)
- Call `sayName()` with the clicked element's `name`-attribute

The advantage of using event-delegation is, that only one event-listener is used. The event would bubble up the DOM tree anyway.
If you were to add a new button dynamically, it would work immediately, as no event-listener needs to be attached.
Also, the reduced amount of event-listener makes your site more resource-friendly.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  sayName(evt.target.name);
});

function sayName(name) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button name="red">Click</button>
  <button name="blue">Click</button>
  <button name="green">Click</button>
</div>
```